# Kibana, grouping values of same field in bar chart

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am currently exploring Kibana and one of the issues I am running into is that I am not able to group together values of the same field to create a bar chart.

Example - Field's name is Country it has 6 unique values

Canada, US, Uk, Germany, India, China.

Now I want to create a bar chart having 3 bars with x-axis having North America(canada and US), Asia( India and China) ...and so on.

I explored filter and sub-buckets but they don't seem to provide grouping of values instead filtering based on the field.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to implement what you require. Please follow the following steps:-

> Click on Visualize Tab & Select Vertical Bar Chart (as per your requirement)
>
> Click on Start from a new Search
>
> In Y-Axis select as Count.
>
> Then select X-Axis
>
> Select Aggregations as **Filters**.
>
> In Filter 1 mention:- **Country:(Canada OR US)**
>
> In Filter 2 mention:- **Country:(India OR China)**
>
> In Filter 3 mention:- **Country:(Uk OR Germany)**

where Country is your field name followed by values.

> Click on Apply to see the 3 Bar Chart as you required :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yuvraj, is there a way to make an Alias as well for the same, i.e. in the filter it could be Country:(India OR China) but on the bar graph it could be "Asia" instead of the ugly field expression :)

Comment: and i see an issue around this - https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2245  , let me explore the kibana that I have to see if it's implemented yet or not!

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2245 and it's not implemented yet! even the latest snapshot version which I could build from source doesn't have it!

Comment: Actually renaming the legend was part of Kibana 3(if i am not wrong), why it has been removed in Kibana 4 is unknown, though it will be added maybe in next Kibana 4.2 release along with specifying different colors for the legend.